# Prove $\vert z\vert\leq \vert \mathfrak{Re}(z)\vert+ \vert \mathfrak{Im}(z)\vert$ where $z$ is a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, proof-writing

Prove $\vert z\vert\leq \vert \mathfrak{Re}(z)\vert+ \vert \mathfrak{Im}(z)\vert$ where $z$ is a complex number

Seems quite simple but I don't know how to.

Comment: Hint: square each side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ |z| = \sqrt{Re(z)^2 + Im(z)^2} $$
$$     \leq \sqrt{Re(z)^2} + \sqrt{Im(z)^2}$$
$$ = |Re(z)| + |Im(z)|$$

The inequality follows since in general for any non-negative $x$ and $y$ we have $\sqrt{x+y} \leq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ (consider the square of both sides)

Answer (score 2):

This is the triangle inequality for the triangle of vertices $0, \, \Re z, \, z$.